# Calling the inline JavaScript on a link using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am modifying an ancient table which has inline JavaScript in the form of `<a href="javascript:<lots of shit>">`. The inline JavaScript works, but it would take months to rewrite it so that it fits my assignment, which is when an outer element is clicked the inline JavaScript should be executed.

I'm sorry if I'm not making any sense, but I have been as thoughtful as to provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8cQb/). (The table aspect shouldn't matter.) TL;DR: when I click one of the colored `div`'s I would like its inner `alert()` to execute and how do I do that?

**Edit.** Also, the link is actually hidden!

**Edit #2.** And, as for now, none of the HTML should be tampered with. Only jQuery/JavaScript.

**Edit #3.** I've updated the script to work with my table. The inner `<span>` is now not needed, I can select the `<a>` directly. Now I would just like to know if I'm using `stopPropagation()` correctly?

Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('table.result-v2 tr.view').bind('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $next = $this.next();

        if ($next.attr('class') == 'detail') {
            var $buttons = $this.find('td.buttons'),
                $link = null;

            if ($next.css('display') == 'none') {
                $link = $buttons.find('a.show-link');
            } else {
                $link = $buttons.find('a.hide-link');
            }

            if ($link != null) {
                eval($link.attr('href')); // evaluate found link
                $link.bind('click', function (event) {
                    event.stopPropagation(); // is this needed when the link never can be clicked (it's hidden)?
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick hack that made your code work. **And just to note that this is totally not how it should be done!**

http://jsfiddle.net/2QaUX/1/

Instead of triggering a click, evaluate the inline script inside the href attribute:

Old:

```
$(function () {
    $('.foo').bind('click', function () {
        $(this).find('.bar').parent().trigger('click');
    });
});​
```

New:

```
$(function () {
    $('.foo').bind('click', function () {
        eval($(this).find('.bar').parent().attr('href'));
    });
    $('.bar').parent().bind('click', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); 
    });
});​
```

Comment: Please include and explain the code in your answer as well. In case the link becomes unavailable, your answer is useless.

Comment: Or like this: `window.location = $(this).find('.bar').parent().attr("href")`;

Comment: Hm, that actually works. I think I'm doing it like this 'til I find a prettier way. Or maybe it's pretty enough.

Comment: Two problems with this solution. 1) `eval` is evil. don't use it if you can avoid it (and you can avoid it here). 2) If the user clicks the actual `<a>`, the alert is triggered twice.

Comment: @jackwanders How is it evil? The `<a>` is actually hidden, but I didn't mention that.

Comment: `eval` simply executes whatever code is represented by the string passed to it; any code using `eval` is very susceptible to abuse, as someone else could alter it to execute any arbitrary code they wanted. Also, if the link is hidden in your actual code, I would suggest hiding it in your demo as well; it changes the nature of the problem.

Comment: @jackwanders I highlighted the part in my answer which indicates about how eval is evil. However your answer about setting window.location basically does the same thing and it would still execute any code that is inside.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle now, with hidden links. I'm using Konstantin Dinevs solution for now.

Comment: I've included `stopPropagation()` in my code now and updated the question. Would you guys care to take a look if it's done correctly? I think you do not need to know how the first lines of selection are done, just know that `$link` will hold one `<a>` to be evaluated.

Comment: If the link is hidden you do not need event.stopPropagation() indeed.

Comment: But it does nothing unwanted when the link is hidden? Maybe someone in the future will activate my solution and the link at the same time, and then this is a safe guard?

Comment: Yeah it is, however if the link stays with display: none, then the actual element is not present on the page (it is in the DOM still), which means that no user event can affect it.

Answer (score 1):

just place that js whithin a function

```
function clikEvent(ele)
{
 //<lots of shit>
}
```

and call it on onclick and replace href js with void like

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0)" onClick='clikEvent(this)'>
```

you have to also tack care of the data passed I have placed parameter ele wich will point the href so you can retrive id of  or any other thing 
if you want to use jQuery

```
$('#idofAtag').click(function(){//<lots of shit>});
```

Comment: Yes, but this is .NET and there's an army of ugly string building, which will probably die if I even touch it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here. One is event propagation. When you click the div, you trigger a click on the link, which is also a click on the div. This creates an infinite loop which will quickly exceed the maximum call stack size. To get around this, you need to do two things:

1. Only execute the `window.location.href` assignment if the user clicked on the `div` and not the `a` within it.
2. If the user DOES click on the `a`, prevent the event from bubbling up to the `div`

The second issue is that the 'click' event on a link won't execute javascript stored in an `href` attribute. what you want to do is set `window.location.href`.

```
$('.foo').on('click', function (e) {
    var link =  $(this).find('.bar').parent('a');
    if(e.target != link.get(0)) {
        window.location.href = link.attr('href');
    }
});
$('.foo').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here's a demo

[**--- jsFiddle DEMO ---**](http://jsfiddle.net/VKhaG/1/)

**- NOTE - I would strongly recommend finding another way to handle this situation, but if you cannot alter the existing links, this option is viable.**

Comment: I will check your solution too. I know this is not the best option, but I would probably have to spend a whole day rewriting the ugly ASP.NET. Or a week, it is that ugly and I'm not even experienced in .NET.